# How to create a multi-key dictionary in PHP?

Tags: php, dictionary

I use a static function to create a PDO object.

It accepts 2 params: 
a string and an object which contains the connection settings (dns, user, pass).

in order to prevent unnecessarily creating duplicate PDO connections with the same name, I tried to create a multi-key dictionary to cache the PDO object in.

Here is what I did:

```
include_once('IPDOSettings.php');

class PDOManager
{
    private static $connections; // array of connections

    public static function getConnection(IPDOSettings $settings, $connection_name = 'default')
    {
        $dictionary_key = array('name' => $connection_name, 'settings' => $settings);
        if(!self::$connections[$dictionary_key])
        {
            $DBH = new PDO($settings->getDNS(),$settings->getUser(),$settings->getPass());
            self::$connections[$dictionary_key] = $DBH;
        }
        return self::$connections[$dictionary_key];
    }

}
```

However after testing this I get this error **Illegal offset type**. After looking it up I find out that you cannot use objects or arrays as keys.

So is there anyway to do what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: You can only use integers and strings as keys.

Comment: @NullUserException, Right, I realize that now, thats not what I am asking. I am asking if there is a different way to achieve what I was after without using arrays as keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really an answer to your question but do you expect `PDOManager::getConnection()` being called multiple times with the same `$connection_name` but different settings? Do you need to store the settings along with the db handle in your cache?

This problem wouldn´t even occur if you´d just store the connections by name:

```
    // my suggestion/idea: use $connection_name as key
    $dictionary_key = $connection_name; 

    if(!self::$connections[$dictionary_key])
    {
        $DBH = new PDO($settings->getDNS(),$settings->getUser(),$settings->getPass());
        self::$connections[$dictionary_key] = $DBH;
    }
    return self::$connections[$dictionary_key];
```

---

**EDIT:**

Well, if you cant just use `$connection_name` as a key, you could combine `$connection_name` and use [`spl_object_hash()`](http://php.net/spl_object_hash) in order to get your key:

```
    $dictionary_key = $connection_name . spl_object_hash($settings);
```

This is much nicer then e. g. using `serialize()` to get a string representation of the `$settings` object.

Comment: Actually yes, I often have to connect to multiple data bases. So "default" connection to DB1 would override "default" connection to DB2.

Comment: What you recommended was what I was going to do originally until I tried to make it support multiple connections to multiple DBs.

Comment: @John Isaacks it was an idea, sometimes easy stuff is the best. Maybe my edit gives you another approach?

Comment: Actually if I understand correctly, using separate settings objects with the same settings (not that that should ever happen!) would return the same string if serialized but different string with spl_object_hash.

Comment: By the way, I think I might just go back to the drawing board all together here, because I think I am over complicating things, and I would prefer not having to pass the settings around every time if I can figure out a solution not to.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [SplObjectStorage](http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.splobjectstorage.php), it allows you to use an object as key.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
$dictionary_key = $connection_name . $settings->toString();
```

Comment: obviously, you need to write a toString function on your `IPDOSettings` object.